# Is there a way to make subdirectory of Group Input in GN?

Tags: geometry-nodes

The common Group Input looks like this:
[image]

If I have many inputs, and want to put ABC and abc into 2 directories,so I can fold what I don't want to see.(something looks like the red circle in the picture).
Is there a way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible, and as far as I know, there are no current plans to do so.